# java was started but returned exit code = -1073740771

Tags: java, myeclipse

Maybe some people have encountered this problem, but my question is quite strange.

After the recent reloading, My eclipse 2014 was installed.

After each close, the following dialog box is popped up. What's the problem?

Error screenshot
[image]

**The following is my MyEclipse configuration:**

```
#utf8 (do not remove)
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_3.2.0.v201103301700
-vm
binary/com.sun.java.jdk7.win32.x86_64_1.7.0.u45/bin/javaw.exe
# binary/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javaw.exe
-install
D:\Software\MyEclipse\MyEclipse Professional 2014
-vmargs
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore
```

Online said that we need to modify VM, my own JDK. After I changed to my JDK, I couldn't get it wrong. It may also be said that it is useless for me to change to jdk1.7 in environmental variables.

Comment: Please don't ever post text as image. Copy paste the text into a code box. If you post real images, use the image button of the online editor and it will be embedded in your post.

Comment: Sorry, reputation is not enough. I can't insert pictures into pages.

Comment: Please read my recommendation again, to understand what I wrote. Take especially a look at sentence 1 and 2. I suggested to post the text of the message as text, not as image.

Comment: unfortunately copying the text out of this dialog box is not possible.

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

These kinds of errors are difficult to investigate as there is insufficient information. However, some things to check:

- Look for a **dump file** associated with the crash
  It may be in the temp folder (see the TEMP Windows environment
  variable for the location of the temp folder) or the MyEclipse
  installation folder.
- Try **uninstalling** and reinstalling MyEclipse.
- Try using a different JDK
  You seem to be saying that you tried this and it worked but then I guess you would not have posted the question if it had. The commented line in your .ini file does not appear to point to a valid external JDK unless you moved it to the `/binary` subfolder.
- Try a **fresh workspace** in case it is workspace related.

I should mention that [MyEclipse 2014](https://www.genuitec.com/available-myeclipse-2014/) is a **very old release**. MyEclipse licenses allow license-holders to use any release, so it may be worth downloading and installing the latest release.
There are plenty of fixes and improvements you're missing out on by sticking with an old release.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 update 1803 have solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Going to the Eclipse Install Folder and then to the Configuration and .settings folder and remove the org.eclipse.ui.def.prefs file worked for me to fix this issue.

Obviously, this issue can happen due to various reasons and this is one of the many things to try